# Best way to keep certain n fresh values in a array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object with 4 arrays inside, like this:

```
let obj = {
  A: [1,2,5,8,10,15,20],
  B: [5,1,5,8,10,18,5],
  C: [1,2,2,8,1,15,4],
  D: [1,2,1,8,8,1,3],
}
```

These arrays are populated in real time, so every time new value arrives it gets pushed to these arrays. All 4 arrays have the same length.

But I have to maintain only the last 50 values, so I'm doing this:

```
if (obj.A.length > 50) {
    obj.A.shift()
    obj.B.shift()
    obj.C.shift()
    obj.D.shift()
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result as above?

Comment: Like, continuously, asynchronously, the arrays of the object are being updated?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 continuously

Comment: How is that being achieved?  Some continuous loop in the script?  You could kick off an async function that will loop and check the arrays itself

Comment: There's going to be periods where one array will have at least one more than the rest, since you can't update four arrays exactly simultaneously. This would be easier to answer if you showed us the code that updates the array. In fact, I'm not sure why you don't do the `shift()` in the code that updates the array...

Comment: I have a function that push the values based on some conditions.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm already doing `shift()`. im just looking for a better way

Comment: We need to know how we can objectively measure how much better you want it to be. Otherwise, you'll just get a bunch of answers with different ways, which is practically infinite.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan performance, because this arrays are updated almost every millisecond

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get better performance than the native function created to remove entries from an array, but it's your question. Please do [edit] your question to include the parameters by which answers will be judged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is an option that you can prototype the method that you wish to achieve on the Array object that will limit the number of objects in the array.

**OPTION 1**

In the next example, you do not need to check that the first array length every time and then assume the length of the others, and each array keeps it owns state.

```js
Array.prototype.pushMax = function(max, value) {
  if (this.length >= max) {
    this.splice(0, this.length - max + 1);
  }
  return this.push(value);
};
const max = 3;
const arr = [];
arr.pushMax(max, 1);
arr.pushMax(max, 2);
arr.pushMax(max, 3);
arr.pushMax(max, 4);
arr.pushMax(max, 5);
console.log(arr);
```

**OPTION 2**

In case you would like to have the newest values at the beginning of the array you could do something like that:

```js
Array.prototype.pushStartMax = function(max, value) {
  if (this.length >= max) {
    this.pop();
  }
  return this.unshift(value);
};
const max = 3;
const a = [];
a.pushStartMax(max, 1);
a.pushStartMax(max, 2);
a.pushStartMax(max, 3);
a.pushStartMax(max, 4);

console.log(a);
```